# Getting months as numerical value in R

Tags: r, date, intervals, numeric, lubridate

I created this for loop to iterate through a list of student records (SU_students) and get the difference between the enrollment begin and enrollment end dates in a new column called "enroll_months".

I'm using the `interval()` function from *lubridate* library and when I use it outside of the loop on a single value of two dates it returns numerical value which is what I'm looking for; to have the months as a numerical value in column in the data frame.

```
for (row in 1:nrow(SU_students)){

  SU_students$enroll_months[row] <- interval(Enrollment_Begin[row], Enrollment_End[row]) %/% months(1)

}
```

Comment: Please read the information at the top of  the [tag:r] tag page and in particular the instructions to provide complete examples including all inputs in reproducible manner and all library statements so anyone else can run them, not just you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `SU_students` is the same length as `Enrollment_Begin` and `Enrollment_end`, you can do this all within a `data.frame`.  I have found it easier to use `lubridate::time_length()` as it feels more intuitive and easier to parameterize if I start changing things.

These functions are *vectorized* so there's no need for the `for` loop to iterate over the elements.

```r
set.seed(42)

df <- data.frame(
  SU_students = letters[1:10],
  Enrollment_Begin = as.Date("2021-10-04") + runif(10, -1, 1) * 100,
  Enrollment_End = as.Date("2021-10-04") + runif(10, -1, 1) * 100
)

df$enroll_months <- lubridate::time_length(lubridate::interval(df$Enrollment_Begin, df$Enrollment_End), "months")
df
#>    SU_students Enrollment_Begin Enrollment_End enroll_months
#> 1            a       2021-12-25     2021-09-25    -3.0133179
#> 2            b       2021-12-30     2021-11-16    -1.4384720
#> 3            c       2021-08-22     2021-12-29     4.2485981
#> 4            d       2021-12-09     2021-08-16    -3.7743148
#> 5            e       2021-11-01     2021-09-26    -1.1630180
#> 6            f       2021-10-07     2021-12-31     2.7478618
#> 7            g       2021-11-20     2022-01-07     1.5912136
#> 8            h       2021-07-22     2021-07-19    -0.1145282
#> 9            i       2021-11-04     2021-09-28    -1.1799681
#> 10           j       2021-11-14     2021-10-16    -0.9337551
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>